# SqlBulkCopy.WriteToServer hangs Thread.Abort is called but not sure why

Tags: c#, linq, large-files, sqlbulkcopy, dml

**Given:**

- A `BenchMark` class that lets me know when something has completed.
- A very large XML file (~120MB) that has been parsed into multiple Lists

Some code:

```
SqlConnection con = null;
SqlTransaction transaction = null;

try
{
  con = getCon(); // gets a new connection object
  con.Open();
  transaction = con.BeginTransaction();

  var bulkCopy = new SqlBulkCopy(con, SqlBulkCopyOptions.Default, transaction)
  {
    BatchSize = 1000,
    DestinationTableName = "Table1"
  };

  // assume that the BenchMark class is working
  b = new BenchMark("Table1");
  bulkCopy.WriteToServer(_insertTable1s.AsDataReader()); // _insertTables1s is a List<Table1>
  b.Complete();
  LogHelper.WriteLogItem(b);

  b = new BenchMark("Table2");
  bulkCopy.DestinationTableName = "Table2";
  bulkCopy.WriteToServer(_insertTable2s.AsDataReader()); // _insertTables2s is a List<Table2>
  b.Complete();
  LogHelper.WriteLogItem(b);

  // etc... this code does a batch insert into about 7 tables all having about 40,000 records being inserted.

  b = new BenchMark("Transaction Commit");
  transaction.Commit();
  b.Complete();
}
catch (Exception e)
{
  transaction.Rollback();

  LogHelper.WriteLogItem(
    LogLevel.Critical,
    LogType.DataProcessing,
    e.ToString());
}
finally
{
  con.Close();
}
```

**The Problem:**

On my local development environment, everything is fine. Its when I run this operation in the cloud that causes it to hang. Using the `LogHelper.WriteLogItem` method, I can watch the progress of this process. I observe it hang randomly on a particular table. No exception is thrown so the transaction isn't rolled back. Say it hangs on `Table2` bulk insert. Using MS SQL Management Studio, I run queries on `Table3`, `Table2` and `Table1` with no issue (this means that the transaction was aborted?)

Since it hangs, I'll go rerun the process. This time it hangs sooner so I might get logs like this:

```
7755   Benchmark   LoadXML took 00:00:04.2432816
7756   Benchmark   Table1 took 00:00:06.3961230
7757   Benchmark   Table2 took 00:00:05.2566890
7758   Benchmark   Table3 took 00:00:08.4900921
7759   Benchmark   Table4 took 00:00:02.0000123
```

... it hangs on Table5 (because the BenchMark never completed). I go to run it again and the rest of the log looks like:

```
7780   Benchmark   LoadXML took 00:00:04.1203923
```

... and it hangs here now.

I'm using rackspace cloud hosting if that helps. I have been able to fix this in the past by deleting all the tables from my dbml file and readding them but this time its not working. I'm wondering if the amount of data being processed is causing the problem?

**EDIT:** The code in this example is run in an Asynchronous thread. I've found out that the Thread is Aborting for an **unknown reason** and I need to find out why to solve this problem.

Comment: Can you try doing commits on the transaction after each bulkcopy, and see what happens then?

Comment: I'll see if that works but that won't solve the problem because the data is versioned and the transaction needs to atomic.

Comment: What type of row counts per bulk insert are you dealing with?

Comment: approximately 40000 for most tables and between 500 and 1500 for one or two of them.

Comment: I did fix the problem by dropping the tables on the server and using SQL Compare to re-sync the table schema. Not the best solution so I'm waiting for someone to come up with a better idea.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because this process is done asynchronously (i.e. a thread is kicked off to handle this) the thread has a problem which aborts it and that is why I get strange behavior where the code stalls at different places. I've solved this by completing this task synchronously (it works but its not ideal).

I guess the real issue is why my thread is aborting since I'm not aborting it in any of my code. I believe that its due to amount of data that is being processed, but I could be wrong.

Either way, I've solved my problem.

Answer (score 1):

If you have admin to your server or database, you can run

```
SELECT * FROM sys.dm_tran_session_transactions
```

to see what transactions are currently active - From [Pinal](http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2008/07/24/sql-server-2005-track-down-active-transactions-using-t-sql/)

Additionally, you can run [sp_lock](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa238824%28v=sql.80%29.aspx) to make sure there isn't something blocking your transaction.

Comment: +1 because this is useful but this won't help me because my dev and production environments are hosted in the cloud so I don't have access to that table/view.